# Run interactive process with automated input

Tags: scala, input, io

I'd like to run a process that requires user input. It may just be typing in a password or answering multiple questions. I know all of the possible questions beforehand but not the order.

**This is a naive attempt:**

```
type Line = String

def runAuto(cmd: String, handlers: Map[Line, OutputStream => Unit]): Unit = {

 cmd.run(new ProcessIO(
   _,
   stdout => {
     val bs = new BufferedSource(stdout)
     for (line <- bs.getLines()) {
       handlers.get(line.trim) match {
         case Some(handler) => handler(stdin) // <- hypothetical
         case _             => println(line)
       }
     } 
     bs.close()
   },
   stderr => {
     val bs = new BufferedSource(stderr)
     bs.getLines().foreach(err => println(s"ERR: $err"))
     bs.close()
   }
 ))
```

}

The main problem is: I don't know how to access the stdin while processing the stdout.